# CSS selector for element with \&quot; \r\n \ special characters

Tags: css

I've encountered below kind of output 1st time and not able to figure out how to get CSS selector out of this

sample data from html

```
<a class="\&quot;custom-fund-name\&quot;\r\n" href="\&quot;\/stocks\/42508\/icici-bank-ltd#overview\&quot;">\r\n ICICI Bank &lt;\/a&gt;\r\n &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n &lt;\/td&gt;\r\n </a>
            
<a class="\&quot;custom-fund-name\&quot;\r\n" href="\&quot;\/stocks\/175842\/tube-investments-of-india-ltd#overview\&quot;">\r\n Tube Investments Of India &lt;\/a&gt;\r\n &lt;\/div&gt;\r\n &lt;\/td&gt;\r\n </a>
```

I tried `a[href*=/stocks/]` but it's not working

My requirement is to get anchor element values namely `ICICI Bank, Tube Investments Of India` etc from HTML output

Comment: why not `a[href*=stocks]` ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please add to the answer section; I can accept.